# GET http://localhost:4200/img/icon-check-white-v2.svg 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, svg, angular2-template

I'm getting this error.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
```

It shows the above script is not able to load.But my html does not contain these scripts. I'm using angular 2. How to solve this issue?
[Scrrenshot for folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asN1w.png)

Comment: Put your img folder in your assets folder

Comment: Can you post image for your folder structure?

Comment: I have added image for my folder structure.

Comment: I don't have used any images in my app. @Wandrille

Comment: Sure you did. Some css file might use it. The scripts you showed above bundled by aot, you don't reference them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the process of AOT, your file structure a bit changes. That's why you should put your static files into the assets folder or use them with absolute path. I guess one of the css files trying to import the image. Put the css files along with images into the assets folder or keep it in the src folder.

Comment: Yes.... Actually I used some predefined UI framework. It directly tries to access the image. Now the error got cleared. Thanks a lot !!!